# Add Microsoft Azure SDK to Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, azure

I'm having problems when I try to Azure SDK to my swift App, I fallowed this steps:
1. I crated my mobile app on my Azure Portal.
2. I downloaded the Azure SDK for swift.
3. On Xcode I add the SDK to my project.
[Here's a capture of my Swift Project Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbypR.png)

4. On Swift I added a bridging header file to called "MisDispositivos-Bridging-Header.h" with the fallowing code:

```
#ifndef MisDispositivos_Bridging_Header_h
#define MisDispositivos_Bridging_Header_h

#import <MicrosoftAzureMobile/MicrosoftAzureMobile.h>

#endif /* MisDispositivos_Bridging_Header_h */
```

5.-Finally I added un the build setting of my project this bridging file on "Swift compiler - General"
[Like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAQMX.png)

When I run my iOS app I have the following error on the bridging header file:

> 'MicrosoftAzureMobile/MicrosoftAzureMobile.h' file not found

I want to know what I'm doing wrong, or if there's another right way to do this, because I'm fallowing this steps from a tutorial

Comment: If you're using Cocoapods, I think you try updating the Pod. It's likely that issue has been resolved in a newer version or `MicrosoftAzureMobile ` hasn't been installed at all

Comment: Follow installation instructions on the project homepage (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-ios-client) carefully